# New project MainActivity Errors

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ37Z.png)When I open Android Studio and open a New project then errors come in MainActivity automatically, without any changes and without any coding.

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: try to clean project

Comment: Dear Same problem,, i clean project but same problem

Comment: remove all imports and reimport files

Comment: post your build.gradle..!!

Comment: first update your android studio

Comment: i have added build.gradle #janki gadhiya

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some imports. Just click on the highlighted classes and press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to import the class

Comment: Thanks a lot After Updating Android Studio the problem is Resolved... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your sdk. OR try changing compile sdk version to a lower version which you currently have in your sdk.